# How can I change the wallet password?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, security

I'm curious if there is a way to change the official CLI or GUI wallet password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CLI:** The new version (v0.11.0.0 at the time of writing) has an option to change your password. Simply type `password` and it'll provide you with an option to change your password. As a general remark, you can type `help` to obtain a list of commands and their options.

**GUI:** Currently aforementioned option isn't implemented (yet). You'd have to create a new wallet by restoring from the 25 word mnemonic seed, which allows you to set a new, different password as well.